# Inserting multiple rows of data in database MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently, I am able to insert my items for one row to the database however, the only issue that I'm running into is that if I add another row of data it does not save the other row just the first one. I'm pretty sure the GET action is correct, I believe the problem lies in the POST action but I'm not sure. Any help is very much appreciated.

This is the code that I have so far:

***Controller***

```
    [HttpGet]

    public ActionResult InsertData(int fiscalYear, int period, int locationID)
    {
       testViewModel viewModel = new testViewModel();

        using (BusinessLogic BLL = new BusinessLogic())
        {


            List<DataList> data = BLL.GetData(fiscalYear, period, locationID);
            List<List<DataDetail>> selecteddata = new List<List<DataDetail>>();

            selecteddata.Add(BLL.GetDataList(fiscalYear, period, locationID));

            viewModel.Selecteddata = selecteddata;
            viewModel.isFirstLoad = false;

        }

        return PartialView("_dataView", viewModel);

    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertData(List<DataList> item)
    {

        using (BusinessLogic BLL = new BusinessLogic())
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {

                    foreach(DataList item in items)
                    {                 
                    BLL.InsertDataItem(item.FiscalYear, item.Period, item.LocationID, item.Status, item.Comment);
                    BLL.SaveChanges();

                }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);

                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");


        }

    }
}
```

}

***View***

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <br />    
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="filters">
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Comments</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr id="addItem">

                        <td><input type="text" id="Status" name="Status" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="Comments" name="Comments" class="form-control" /></td>                   
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
    </div>

    <div class="">

        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-block" />
    </div>

}
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 1;
        $("#add_row").click(function () {
            $('#addItem' + i).html("<td><input name='ActionItem" + i + "' type='text' class='form-control'  /> </td><td><input  name='Asignee" + i + "' type='text' class='form-control'></td><td><input  name='DateAssigned" + i + "' type='date' class='form-control'></td><td><input  name='DueDate" + i + "' type='date' class='form-control'></td><td><input  name='Status" + i + "' type='text' class='form-control'></td><td><input  name='Comments" + i + "' type='text' class='form-control'></td>");

            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addItem' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
            i++;
        });
        $("#delete_row").click(function () {
            if (i > 1) {
                $("#addItem" + (i - 1)).html('');
                i--;
            }
        });

    });
```

**--UPDATE--**

The "InsertDataItem" method comes from the business logic class. The following code adds the rows

***Method***

```
    public int InsertDataItem(int fiscalYear, int period, int locationID, string status, string comments)
        {

            var dataList = GetData(fiscalYear, period, locationID);
            DataList items = new DataList()
            {

                FiscalYear = fiscalYear,
                Period = period,
                LocationID = locationID,

                Status = status,
                Comments = comments
            };

            // Inserts row
           entity.DataLists.Add(items);

            SaveChanges();

            return items.ID;
        }
```

Comment: Which part of your code adds other row? Are you getting any error?

Comment: You had written `BLL.InsertDataItem(item.FiscalYear, item.Period, item.LocationID, item.Status, item.Comment);` - which will only insert one row. You need `For` `Loop` for each List `item`

Comment: The Model `DataList ` will contain one set of values. It is not sending `List` to the controller. So instead use `List<DataList>` and make a `For` Loop to save changes

Comment: Thank you! Should I use a for loop or a foreach?

Comment: So I just added the foreach statement and now I'm getting an error saying "Check to determine if the object is null before calling the method." Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller

```
List<DataList> data = BLL.GetData(fiscalYear, period, locationID);
```

Is not used?

In the post method:

```
public ActionResult InsertData(DataList item)
```

The item contains a single element I think (which has Status, Comment, etc ), while you should have a list of elements. The name DataList is also misleading, as it now contains only 1 element.

If you are interested I have a post on how to pass a list of objects to the controller :)

http://debuxing.com/model-binding-to-a-list-of-objects/

Comment: Thank you @coffeetime, I appreciate that!